# Firebase keeps renaming my childs to tutored

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how I am pushing the data,it includes me considering whether that sharedpref item is null and if its null,calls the method that generates usernames and for good measure restarting the activity so that the change is seen.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("SophiePrefs", 0);

                mUsername = prefs.getString("username", null);
                if(mUsername!=null){
                    mFirebaseBackupHistory.child(mUsername).push().setValue(allthemsgs);
                }else {
                    setupUsername();
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                }
```

This is how I get the username:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("ChatPrefs", 0); 
mUsername = prefs.getString("username", null); 
if (mUsername == null) { 
    Random r = new Random(); // Assign a random user name if we don't have one saved. 
    mUsername = "Client" + r.nextInt(100000); 
    prefs.edit().putString("username", mUsername).commit(); 
}
```

And I Keep getting this

```
{
  "tutored" : {
    "-KSRR7nDjf01iyexk_wl" : {
      "left" : false,
      "text" : "hi"
    },
    "-KSRR8LPWohiIfA0BnCp" : {
      "left" : true,
      "text" : "Hey,I'm Sophie,What would you like to know"
    },
    "-KSRR9xHoEf1g-Jf8BHN" : {
      "left" : false,
      "text" : "shit"
    },
    "-KSRRACSJXn8db6JhGDE" : {
      "left" : true,
      "text" : "Wait a moment as I look for the answer"
    },
    "-KSRRBuFcwTJpjIh9qum" : {
      "left" : false,
      "text" : "this sucks"
    },
    "-KSRRBy2gFcY2U7iLaXv" : {
      "left" : true,
      "text" : "Wait a moment as I look for the answer"
    }
  }
}
```

No mUsername is not tutored...its a dynamic string i generate for everyone with the app

Comment: Can u show ?how are u getting values of mUsername?

Comment: `SharedPreferences prefs = getApplication().getSharedPreferences("ChatPrefs", 0);
        mUsername = prefs.getString("username", null);
        if (mUsername == null) {
            Random r = new Random();
            // Assign a random user name if we don't have one saved.
            mUsername = "Client" + r.nextInt(100000);
            prefs.edit().putString("username", mUsername).commit();

        }`

Comment: it seems mUsername is null. Check it first by printing.

Comment: i check if its not null before using it,,,,,and the same username is being sent to another child.